# Can't resolve localhost when not on home network

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to run my node app on localhost. After starting it reports that the app is running on localhost:8080. When I am on my home network I'm allowed to access my app on https://localhost:8080. When I am connected to work VPN or work wifi, my /etc/resolv.conf is generated differently and I'm no longer allowed to access my app on the localhost URL. I am able to access the app by giving the direct IP (which will not be 127.0.0.1 when I am on work network/VPN).

Please help me set my network configuration so that I can always access my app on https://localhost:8080

(Note that I am dependant on allowing automatic changes of my /etc/resolv.conf file to be able to access domains only exposed through the work nameserver.)

[image: Network details]

Comment: '[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)' is literally the host computer on your local network.  At home it's whatever machine is running apache/nginx.  At work, it's probably a server running IIS, or some 'cloud' computer the company leases. Your question is like asking how to use your kitchen to make coffee while you are at work.  You *could* set up a remote desktop connection to home and then view localhost pages, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: The app is hosted on my local computer in both cases, but still not reachable at https://localhost:8080

Comment: Some VPNs have a setting built in that can allow you to still communicate with device on your local area network, but if yours doesn't have that, take a look at what this website says. [Accessing LAN while in VPN](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/113798-accessing-local-network-resources-while-using-vpn)

Comment: @heap1  Oh, you are running it from your work machine?  Then you may be able to also run the webserver from that machine.  This should allow you to access localhost.

Comment: @mcalex Yes. The webserver is also hosted locally. It's for local testing during development. I found that I have to specify `https://` in the URL for it to be able to resolve under certain circumstances. Not sure if it's related to the changing of DNS when connected to VPN anymore...